# Azure Data Factory Error code":9056,"message":"Cannot connect to SQL Server"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy a file data from Azure Blob storage to Azure SQL DB just for my learning. I cannot able to create the linked service for Azure SQL db destination as it is giving the error. I can able to connect fine from my local SSMS to the Azure SQL server but not from AZURE data factory. I turned on Allow access to Azure services. I am using the default integration runtime (AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime). I also did Add client IP by adding my current IP address to the rule list

Comment: Which `Authentication type` are you using in the sql database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an Azure Integration Runtime with the same region as the SQL server. Sometimes the auto resolve cannot reach the sql server.

Hope this helped!